# Does Jackson require complete input?

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I'm doing a little bit of tinkering for fun with Jackson and I stumbled across the following.
Assume you're working in a system which is operating on a large amount of files.
The desire is to keep memory consumption low and read those files in a non-blocking asynchronous manner.

So, we create a ByteBuffer with a low amount of bytes allocated (say 1024) and a AsynchronousFileChannel for each file (which are > 1024 bytes), then read from the buffers.
Ideally we start parsing as soon as a buffer's Future has completed so we're not waiting on anything then, clear the buffer and continue parsing the file.

Now to the best of my knowledge this is not possible because Jackson will throw an Exception because it needs "complete" input.

However, since I'm not sure, is there a way around this?
Or, does Jackson always require complete input before it can start parsing?

Comment: You can always use `InputStream`, instead of entire string, jackson has methods for that - [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.Class)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON into Jackson using a stream/object approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466166/parsing-json-into-jackson-using-a-stream-object-approach)

Comment: As far as i can tell, using an `InputStream` or `JsonParser` is still blocking, and I don't think you can prevent this with Jackson, but also Gson and JSON-B. I'm working on a project where I want to use reactive communicating with a backend, but as far as I can tell even frameworks like Spring (Boot) and Quarkus first collect all the data before parsing.

Comment: @Chaosfire Unfortunately that does not do the trick. If I'm partially reading a file into a small buffer, or lets flip it, I'm reading from a "very large" file into a reasonably sized buffer then jackson will complain whether I pass the data as a byte[] or an InputStream regardless.

Comment: @GaëlJ Unfortunately it does not. This still requires that I've got input which is "complete" in other words, Jackson must be able to parse the full byte[].

Comment: If you're going to pass the whole large file through those buffers, there is no reason to do that manually. Just use an `InputStream`. The end result is the same and you won't need to do anything custom. If you really need those buffers, write an InputStream-like API around it so that you can pass that into Jackson. But that's just making your own life difficult.

Comment: @Jorn The problem is that AsyncFileChannel returns a ByteBuffer and not an InputStream, if I'd use an InputStream I would still have to write something custom to wrap the ByteBuffers in an InputStream.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do if you insist on using Channels and ByteBuffers

Comment: @Byebye Jackson provides utility for that - [ByteBufferBackedInputStream](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.4.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ByteBufferBackedInputStream.html), is there a reason you can't use it?

Comment: @Chaosfire Since the file is larger in size than the bytebuffer I use to read from the AsyncFileChannel I will have to read multiple times. So I would either have to pool everything into a single bytebuffer ( or just increase the initial buffer size) or, I could attempt to read each bytebuffer as soon as it becomes available.

There is no actual reason though, I was just wondering whether Jackson could handle this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Jackson requires full input. Your way to work around it is to read your file by chunks into a larger buffer on your server side and parse it once the file is fully read. But that negates your low memory footprint requirement. Another possible trick is that if your file contains several Json documents, is to determine when you have a complete doc and parse it than, without waiting for the entire file to be read. But this is more complex solution as you have to do some preliminary parsing to determine that you got the entire Json doc